# PyTorch: How to define a new neural network that utilizes transfer learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am migrating from Keras/TF frameworks and I have litte troubles understanding the transfer learning process in PyTorch.

I want to use pytorch-lightning framework and I want to switch between different neural networks in one script.

Per this [example](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new-project.html) we can switch between different neural networks in their implementation:

```
class BERT(pl.LightningModule):
def __init__(self, model_name, task):
    self.task = task

    if model_name == 'transformer':
        self.net = Transformer()
    elif model_name == 'my_cool_version':
        self.net = MyCoolVersion()
```

The question is: **how to create a new neural network that extends the nn.Module and utilizes transfer learning process?**

My own implementation looks like this: I am using vgg16 network and replaced the classifier layer with only one fc with two output neurons.

```
class VGGNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGGNetwork, self).__init__()
        # vgg16 is the default model here, we can use bn etc...
        self.model = vgg16(pretrained=True)

        # removing the last three layers of classifier only 2 ...
        self.model.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(512 * 7 * 7, 2))

def forward(self, x):
    return self.model.forward(x)
```

Is this the correct way how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

you can freeze weights and bais for the neural network layer except for the last layer.

you can use **requires_grad = False**

```
for param in model_conv.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

you can find more about this at the following link 
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html

Comment: this is not the question at all. I am not asking about layer freeze.

Answer (score 0):

https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.1/transfer_learning.html

```py
    ...

class AutoEncoder(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        self.encoder = Encoder()
        self.decoder = Decoder()

class CIFAR10Classifier(pl.LightingModule):
    def __init__(self):
        # init the pretrained LightningModule
        self.feature_extractor = AutoEncoder.load_from_checkpoint(PATH)
        self.feature_extractor.freeze()

        # the autoencoder outputs a 100-dim representation and CIFAR-10 has 10 classes
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(100, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        representations = self.feature_extractor(x)
        x = self.classifier(representations)
        ...
```